# Linking Crypto++ fails when building a C++ project using CMake

Tags: c++, cmake, crypto++

I have the following project structure:

```
myexec/
|-main.cpp
|-hashing.cpp
|-hashing.h
|-CMakeLists.txt
```

My little software needs [Crypto++](https://www.cryptopp.com/) whose latest version I built under this path:

```
C:\Users\myuser\cryptopp
```

`CMakeLists.txt` is:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.8)

project ("MyExec")

add_executable(MyExec "main.cpp", "hashing.h", "hashing.cpp")

find_library(CRYPTOPP_LIB cryptopp "C:/Users/myuser/cryptopp/Win32/DLL_Output/Debug")
target_link_libraries(MyExec PUBLIC "${CRYPTOPP_LIB}")

target_include_directories(MyExec PUBLIC "C:/Users/myuser/cryptopp")
```

`hashing.cpp` is:

```
#define CRYPTOPP_ENABLE_NAMESPACE_WEAK 1 // Needed to use MD5 in Crypto++

#include <cryptlib.h>
#include <md5.h>

#include "Hashing.h"

using namespace CryptoPP;

std::string get_hash(const std::string& str)
{
    std::string digest;
    Weak::MD5 hash;

    hash.Update((const byte*)(str.data()), str.size());
    digest.resize(hash.DIGESTSIZE);
    hash.Final((byte*)&digest[0]);

    return digest;
}
```

#### Problem

As I compile this in VS 2019 Community on my Win10 x64 machine, I get this linking error:

```
C:\Users\myuser\Documents\myexec\out\build\x64-Debug (default)\Hashing.cpp.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __cdecl CryptoPP::Algorithm::Algorithm(bool)" (??0Algorithm@CryptoPP@@QEAA@_N@Z) referenced in function "public: __cdecl CryptoPP::HashTransformation::HashTransformation(void)" (??0HashTransformation@CryptoPP@@QEAA@XZ)
C:\Users\myuser\Documents\myexec\out\build\x64-Debug (default)\Hashing.cpp.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual bool __cdecl CryptoPP::HashTransformation::TruncatedVerify(unsigned char const *,unsigned __int64)" (?TruncatedVerify@HashTransformation@CryptoPP@@UEAA_NPEBE_K@Z)
C:\Users\myuser\Documents\myexec\out\build\x64-Debug (default)\Hashing.cpp.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual void __cdecl CryptoPP::IteratedHashBase<unsigned int,class CryptoPP::HashTransformation>::Update(unsigned char const *,unsigned __int64)" (?Update@?$IteratedHashBase@IVHashTransformation@CryptoPP@@@CryptoPP@@UEAAXPEBE_K@Z) referenced in function "class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > __cdecl get_hash(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &)" (?get_hash@@YA?AV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@AEBV34@@Z)
C:\Users\myuser\Documents\myexec\out\build\x64-Debug (default)\Hashing.cpp.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual unsigned char * __cdecl CryptoPP::IteratedHashBase<unsigned int,class CryptoPP::HashTransformation>::CreateUpdateSpace(unsigned __int64 &)" (?CreateUpdateSpace@?$IteratedHashBase@IVHashTransformation@CryptoPP@@@CryptoPP@@UEAAPEAEAEA_K@Z)
C:\Users\myuser\Documents\myexec\out\build\x64-Debug (default)\Hashing.cpp.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual void __cdecl CryptoPP::IteratedHashBase<unsigned int,class CryptoPP::HashTransformation>::Restart(void)" (?Restart@?$IteratedHashBase@IVHashTransformation@CryptoPP@@@CryptoPP@@UEAAXXZ)
C:\Users\myuser\Documents\myexec\out\build\x64-Debug (default)\Hashing.cpp.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual void __cdecl CryptoPP::IteratedHashBase<unsigned int,class CryptoPP::HashTransformation>::TruncatedFinal(unsigned char *,unsigned __int64)" (?TruncatedFinal@?$IteratedHashBase@IVHashTransformation@CryptoPP@@@CryptoPP@@UEAAXPEAE_K@Z)
C:\Users\myuser\Documents\myexec\out\build\x64-Debug (default)\Hashing.cpp.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "protected: virtual unsigned __int64 __cdecl CryptoPP::IteratedHashBase<unsigned int,class CryptoPP::HashTransformation>::HashMultipleBlocks(unsigned int const *,unsigned __int64)" (?HashMultipleBlocks@?$IteratedHashBase@IVHashTransformation@CryptoPP@@@CryptoPP@@MEAA_KPEBI_K@Z)
C:\Users\myuser\Documents\myexec\out\build\x64-Debug (default)\Hashing.cpp.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: static void __cdecl CryptoPP::Weak1::MD5::InitState(unsigned int *)" (?InitState@MD5@Weak1@CryptoPP@@SAXPEAI@Z) referenced in function "protected: virtual void __cdecl CryptoPP::IteratedHashWithStaticTransform<unsigned int,struct CryptoPP::EnumToType<enum CryptoPP::ByteOrder,0>,64,16,class CryptoPP::Weak1::MD5,0,0>::Init(void)" (?Init@?$IteratedHashWithStaticTransform@IU?$EnumToType@W4ByteOrder@CryptoPP@@$0A@@CryptoPP@@$0EA@$0BA@VMD5@Weak1@2@$0A@$0A@@CryptoPP@@MEAAXXZ)
C:\Users\myuser\Documents\myexec\out\build\x64-Debug (default)\Hashing.cpp.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: static void __cdecl CryptoPP::Weak1::MD5::Transform(unsigned int *,unsigned int const *)" (?Transform@MD5@Weak1@CryptoPP@@SAXPEAIPEBI@Z) referenced in function "protected: virtual void __cdecl CryptoPP::IteratedHashWithStaticTransform<unsigned int,struct CryptoPP::EnumToType<enum CryptoPP::ByteOrder,0>,64,16,class CryptoPP::Weak1::MD5,0,0>::HashEndianCorrectedBlock(unsigned int const *)" (?HashEndianCorrectedBlock@?$IteratedHashWithStaticTransform@IU?$EnumToType@W4ByteOrder@CryptoPP@@$0A@@CryptoPP@@$0EA@$0BA@VMD5@Weak1@2@$0A@$0A@@CryptoPP@@MEAAXPEBI@Z)
C:\Users\myuser\cryptopp\Win32\DLL_Output\Debug\cryptopp.lib : warning LNK4272: library machine type 'x86' conflicts with target machine type 'x64'
C:\Users\myuser\Documents\myexec\out\build\x64-Debug (default)\myexec.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 9 unresolved externals
  ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

What am I doing wrong here?

---

### Edit

After good feedback from @botje and @nelsonsule, I fixed the x64 issue:

```
find_library(CRYPTOPP_LIB cryptopp "C:/Users/myuser/cryptopp/x64/DLL_Output/Release")
```

This is now causing the arch mismatch warning to go away, but I will get 2 linking errors:

```
C:\Users\myuser\Documents\myexec\out\build\x64-Debug (default)\Hashing.cpp.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: static void __cdecl CryptoPP::Weak1::MD5::InitState(unsigned int *)" (?InitState@MD5@Weak1@CryptoPP@@SAXPEAI@Z) referenced in function "protected: virtual void __cdecl CryptoPP::IteratedHashWithStaticTransform<unsigned int,struct CryptoPP::EnumToType<enum CryptoPP::ByteOrder,0>,64,16,class CryptoPP::Weak1::MD5,0,0>::Init(void)" (?Init@?$IteratedHashWithStaticTransform@IU?$EnumToType@W4ByteOrder@CryptoPP@@$0A@@CryptoPP@@$0EA@$0BA@VMD5@Weak1@2@$0A@$0A@@CryptoPP@@MEAAXXZ)
C:\Users\myuser\Documents\myexec\out\build\x64-Debug (default)\Hashing.cpp.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: static void __cdecl CryptoPP::Weak1::MD5::Transform(unsigned int *,unsigned int const *)" (?Transform@MD5@Weak1@CryptoPP@@SAXPEAIPEBI@Z) referenced in function "protected: virtual void __cdecl CryptoPP::IteratedHashWithStaticTransform<unsigned int,struct CryptoPP::EnumToType<enum CryptoPP::ByteOrder,0>,64,16,class CryptoPP::Weak1::MD5,0,0>::HashEndianCorrectedBlock(unsigned int const *)" (?HashEndianCorrectedBlock@?$IteratedHashWithStaticTransform@IU?$EnumToType@W4ByteOrder@CryptoPP@@$0A@@CryptoPP@@$0EA@$0BA@VMD5@Weak1@2@$0A@$0A@@CryptoPP@@MEAAXPEBI@Z)
C:\Users\myuser\Documents\myexec\out\build\x64-Debug (default)\myexec.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 2 unresolved externals
```

Comment: "C:\Users\myuser\cryptopp\Win32\DLL_Output\Debug\cryptopp.lib : warning LNK4272: library machine type 'x86' conflicts with target machine type 'x64'" You're trying to link a x86 cryptopp library against an x64 MyExec binary

Comment: That is a warning... is it really the cause of this issue?

Comment: It is very much the cause.

Comment: Ok I see, my previous comment was actually silly... I did not see the warning and I understand that the arch being different is clearly an issue... I guess I need to rebuild the library

Comment: @Andry The LNK2019 error means that there are methods defined in the "CryptoPP::Weak1::MD5" namespace (probably a separate header file) that it can't find in the library file (lib). As you're definitely linking to the lib now, check that you're using the correct header files that correspond to that lib.

Comment: @AStopher I am pretty sure because all the header files are inside the root folder of the sources of `Cryptopp`. There is no other path to header files than `C:/Users/myuser/cryptopp`.

Comment: What puzzles me is that it is not complaining about functions I am using, but internal stuff. Fx `InitState` is something I am not using directly in my project...

Comment: Mmm I see the problem might be here: https://cryptopp-users.narkive.com/QZVBuSmX/cryptopp-5-6-2-and-visual-studio-2010-lnk2019

Comment: Well, I've managed to build this.

Comment: @Den-Jason How? With the same CMakeLists.txt I provided? Did you use the static library or the dll?

Comment: See my answer #2

Answer (score 3):

`C:\Users\myuser\cryptopp\Win32\DLL_Output\Debug\cryptopp.lib : warning LNK4272: library machine type 'x86' conflicts with target machine type 'x64'`

Your problem seems to be coming from here. you're running on a higher architecture of OS (`x64`) while linking to a crypto library designed for a lower OS architecture (`x86`) which is a 32 bit. consider linking to a cyrpto library designed for `x64`

Comment: I still get that error, but I can see that it is using the old path. Is CMake caching stuff from the CMakeLists file?

Comment: I applied your suggestion and rebuilt Crypto++ targeting x64. The warning is now gone, but two linking errors are still there...

Answer (score 1):

OK I have managed to build a minimum reproducible example that works.

Download https://github.com/weidai11/cryptopp and extract to `E:\__experiments\cryptopp\cryptopp-master`

Open `cryptest.sln` in Visual Studio, select x64 configuration and build.

Under directory E:__experiments\cryptopp\testprog:

```
build\
src\main.cpp
CMakeLists.txt
```

CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.15)

# this enables the MSVC_RUNTIME_LIBRARY property for slightly older CMake versions
cmake_policy(SET CMP0091 NEW)

project ("MD5test")

add_executable(MD5test "src/main.cpp")

# this is equivalent to setting C/C++ -> Code Generation -> Runtime Library in the Visual Studio project property pages
set_property(TARGET MD5test 
             PROPERTY MSVC_RUNTIME_LIBRARY "MultiThreaded$<$<CONFIG:Debug>:Debug>")

find_library(CRYPTOPP_LIB cryptlib.lib HINTS E:/__experiments/cryptopp/cryptopp-master/x64/Output/*)

target_link_libraries(MD5test PUBLIC "${CRYPTOPP_LIB}")

target_include_directories(MD5test PUBLIC "E:/__experiments/cryptopp/cryptopp-master")
```

src\main.cpp:

```
#define CRYPTOPP_ENABLE_NAMESPACE_WEAK 1 // Needed to use MD5 in Crypto++

#include <cryptlib.h>
#include <md5.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

#define byte unsigned char

using std::string;

string get_hash(const string& str)
{
    string digest;
    CryptoPP::Weak::MD5 hash;

    hash.Update((const byte*)(str.data()), str.size());
    digest.resize(hash.DIGESTSIZE);
    hash.Final((byte*)&digest[0]);

    return digest;
}


int main (int argc, char** argv)
{
    string hash = get_hash("coconuts");
    std::cout << hash << std::endl;
    return 0;
```

Open a "Developer command prompt for VS2019" and navigate to the testprog dir, then enter:

```
del build
mkdir build
cd build
cmake  -DCMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE:BOOL=ON ..
cmake --build .

Debug\MD5test.exe
```

Alternatively write a batch file in the test root, `do_build.bat`, so you can use a plain command prompt window:

```
call "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\Common7\Tools\VsDevCmd.bat"
cd .
del /F /Q build
rd /S /Q build
mkdir build
cd build
cmake  -DCMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE:BOOL=ON ..
cmake --build .
cd ..
```