# CMake: How to link libraries in my project?

Tags: c++, cmake, visual-studio-2019, cmakelists-options

I created a visual studio hello world project. Now I want add a library, pugixml. How can I do?

In CMakeList:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VESION 3.18)
set(PROJECT_NAME hello_world)

PROJECT($(project_name) CXX C)

target_link_libraries( ??? )
```

My pugixml library is:

```
pugi/lib/cmake/..#other stuff
pugi/lib/pkgconfig/..#other stuff
pugi/lib/pugilib.lib
pugi/bin/pugixml.dll
pugi/include/pugicongif.hpp pugixml.hpp
```

How can I include this library?

Comment: I have an example here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64334300/linking-crypto-fails-when-building-a-c-project-using-cmake/64337995#64337995

Comment: You will typically use [`find_package`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/find_package.html) or [`find_library`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/find_library.html), followed by [`target_link_libraries`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_link_libraries.html) and likely [`target_include_directories`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_include_directories.html).  But in order to use the latter two, you need a target to be a client of the library, e.g. via [`add_executable`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_executable.html)

Comment: Note, that variable [PROJECT_NAME](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/PROJECT_NAME.html) is set by CMake. Do not set it manually (with `set` command).

Comment: I have created the find.cmake and used find_library but, in visual studio with the include, does not find the library. The path are correctly recognized in cmake. Where I wrong? Any hint?