# Using CMAKE find_package with SDL2

Tags: c++, cmake, sdl-2

I've got a project that uses CMAKE, and needs to link SDL2. I'm trying to understand how find_package works. At one point in the past, I was able to get find_package to work by supplying my own FindSDL2.cmake, but after some new linker errors, I decided to try a different apporoach. The reading I'm doing seems to imply that, after I've installed the libsdl2-dev package, I should be able to just use find_package(SDL2 REQUIRED) and then target_link_libraries(Suqua PRIVATE SDL2::SDL2), but cmake throws a package not found error. Do I need to provide a custom FindSDL2.cmake?

CMakeLists.txt

```
    cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.8)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

find_package(SDL2 CONFIG REQUIRED)

file(GLOB source_files
    "src/*.cpp"
    "header/*.h"
)

add_library(Suqua ${source_files} "src/glad.c" )

target_include_directories(Suqua PUBLIC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/header)
target_include_directories(Suqua PUBLIC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../include)

target_link_libraries(Suqua PRIVATE SDL2::SDL2 enet)

if(UNIX)
    target_link_libraries(Suqua PRIVATE stdc++fs)
endif()
```

Error

```
CMake Error at Suqua/CMakeLists.txt:13 (add_library):
  Target "Suqua" links to target "SDL2::SDL2" but the target was not found.
  Perhaps a find_package() call is missing for an IMPORTED target, or an
  ALIAS target is missing?
```

Thank you, and if you have any other critiques of my CMakeLists, they'd be greatly appreciated!

Comment: provide HINTS with `find_package` - see example here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/64337995/1607937

Comment: GLOBbing is now deprecated, plus 3.8 is now quite an old min-vers.  There should also be a `project` statement very near the beginning.   I recommend getting a copy of Craig Scott's book, "Professional CMake" - https://crascit.com/

Comment: "cmake throws a package not found error" - No, this is wrong interpretation of CMake output. The `find_package` call has been **succeeded**. What is wrong is that call doesn't define `SDL2::SDL2` target as one could expect.

Comment: @Den-Jason Either I'm doing it wrong, or no luck.
find_package(SDL2 REQUIRED HINTS /usr/lib/x86-64-linux-gnu/)
Thanks for the book reccomendation! I'll get a copy.

Comment: @Tsyvarev
So its finding the package, but not defining the target? how is that happening?
The debug output certainly doesn't appear to contain anything about being unable to find the package.

Comment: It seems that the script `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/SDL2/sdl2-config.cmake`, shipped with the [libsdl2-dev](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/amd64/libsdl2-dev/filelist), doesn't create an IMPORTED targets but sets variables like `SDL2_INCLUDE_DIRS` and `SDL2_LIBRARIES`. You can open this script and check that it contains only `set` and `string` commands. The IMPORTED target `SDL2::SDL2` is created by the script `SDL2Config.cmake`, which is probably created only when you build and install SDL2 from sources.

Answer (score 0):

Answer supplied by Tsyvarev

When using an installed library (not built from source), use the SD2_LIBRARIES variable.

On another note, I actually fixed this earlier, but assumed I was doing something wrong when I got a linker error relating to linking CMAKE_DL_LIBS, which I'd removed because I assumed it didn't do anything :/
Definitely gonna read through that CMake book. Thanks all!